# C# Mono - Low Level Keyboard Hook

Tags: c#, mono, keyboard-hook

I'm using code that I found on the [CodeProject.com for a low-level keyboard hook](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSLLKeyboardHook.aspx).  The only problem is it uses external DLL calls that don't work in mono.  I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to accomplish the same thing as that code, but will run in both Windows using .net, and Linux using mono?

Edit:  Clarifying what I'm trying to do:
I'm making a [Dashboard like application](http://joel-llamaduck.blogspot.com/).  The program sits in the system tray and when the user presses the hot-key, it will pop up all the gadgets.  So the program doesn't have focus, so typically it won't catch any keystrokes, so I'm using the low-level keyboard hook and I hook the two keys that the user defines as the hot-keys.  But I'm using a Windows DLL call for that, which doesn't work in Linux using mono.  So I'm wondering if there's a way to do the same thing, but will run in Linux using mono?

Comment: I deleted my answer, as it didn't really answer how to add a low-level keyboard hook on Linux.

Comment: I edited and added some clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to get this behavior using only .Net. You have to use a binary driver for each platform you run on (Windows, Linux, Mac OS). It might be possible to use only P/Invoke (detect what OS you are running on, call appropriate system libraries) so that you won't have to distribute any "extra" dll/so/dylib.

Comment: so I'd have to do one thing for windows and another in linux?
Ok, I kindof figured I might have to do that.  How would I do it in linux then?

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing what you are trying to capture, it's hard to be sure what will work for you.  You may want to look at using Application.AddMessageFilter.

An example is here: http://dn.codegear.com/article/30129